# How to combine tables in access 2010

Tags: ms-access, join, union

I am a newbie with access and I need some help.

I am trying to combine 2 tables in access.

```
Table 1:
ID      First_Name   Last_Name     Gender
12345   John         Doe           F
22345   Jane         Clin          M

Table 2:
ID       First_Name   Last_Name     Grade
12345    Curt         Doe            2
12345    Carry        Doe            3
12345    Sid          Doe            1
22345    Mel          Clin           7
```

How do I write the SQL in Access to display

```
ID      First_Name   Last_Name     Gender   Grade
12345   John         Doe           F
12345   Curt         Doe           M         2
12345   Carry        Doe                     3
12345   Sid          Doe                     1
22345   Jane         Clin          M
22345   Mel          Clin                    7
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please provide more information about what you tried and what happend. Maybe it is good idea to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Using your sample data why does Curt Doe have a gender listed?  And why do they all have the same ID?  How does table 1 and table 2 relate?  based on first and last names?  (not a good design)  It appears you need to generate a master set of names so first union the two tables based on ID, first_name, Last_name.  then take that derived table and join to table2 to get the grades.  and table 1 to get gender; but that doesn't explain curt having a gender defined.

Comment: Is this two tables of parents/children?  i.e. is John Doe a parent to Curt, Carry and Sid?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.First_Name, A.Last_Name, A.Gender, B.Grade
FROM TABLE_1 A 
INNER JOIN TABLE_2 B 
  on A.ID=B.ID;
```

Did you make these tables or is this something you're stuck with? If we assume that the ID is the common item in these then you don't want to put First_Name and Last_Name in both tables. Just include the ID in both tables to make the link.
If you want to include all from TABLE_2 regardless of whether or not they exist in TABLE_2 then change INNER JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN.

**EDIT**
I see I made a mistake in assuming that TABLE_1 was a primary. I think what you actually want in this particular case would be a union.

```
SELECT U.ID, U.First_Name, U.Last_Name, U.Gender, U.Grade 
FROM (SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, '' AS Grade 
      FROM TABLE_1
      UNION
      SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_Name, '' AS Gender, Grade 
      FROM TABLE_2) U
```

HTH,
Mike

Comment: If there's overlap on names/ID's between the two tables then you'd get duplicate records in the result.  We still need to understand how curt obtained a gender given sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've provided a union and two left joins should do the trick.  Though this is a terrible database design or the sample data is bad.

Here's why

1. The ID's are the same for all users
2. it appears one has to join on First and last Name and we all know spelling errors and name changes become difficult to manage thus data entry errors cause us to get improper results.
3. Curt has a gender in your sample results yet none exists in sample data.  Where did this value come from?
4. I'm assuming the ID's should be what relate records; but we have to join on ID, first, and last names to possibly get a unique record.  What are the PKs on those tables without this knowledge our answers are pure guesses.
5. if we assume Table1's PK is ID, and Table2 ID is a Foreign key to table1 then we should just be able to join on ID; but the sample data doesn't reflect this.  So what are the PK's and FK's on each table?

.

Given the sample data and desired results; my approach would be to union all the IDs and names from both tables into one set of data then outer join this data back to table1 and table2 to get the gender and grades.  Ideally we'd just be joining on ID; but the sample data doesn't seem to indicate the ID being a primary/Foreign key for either table.

```
SELECT Der.ID, Der.First_name, Der.Last_name, T1.Gender, T2.Grade
FROM (SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_name
      FROM table1
      UNION 
      SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_name
      FROM Table2) DER
LEFT JOIN Table1 T1
 on T1.Id = Der.ID
and T1.First_name = Der.First_name
and T1.Last_name = Der.Last_name
LEFT JOIN table2 T2
 on T2.Id = Der.ID
and T2.First_name = Der.First_name
and T2.Last_name = Der.Last_name
```

Why?

Because neither table contains a complete list of names you want in your results but combined they do; thus the need to derive a table with all names and IDs.  The outer joins then allow us to get the gender and grades for the unioned set.

But before progressing further; i'd really look at the table design and understand the PK/FK relationships and ensure your data is accurate.  It seems table 1 is a "persons" table whereas table2 is more of a grades for each class/grade/year table.  This would be a 1:M relationship; and as such the ID of the persons table should be a FK to the "grades" table which should have it's on PK or composite key for class year person.  and then you wouldn't have to have the names in the grades table..  unless you were concerned about tracking name changes for each grade/year/semester...